# Embed google photo sphere in website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-street-view, photosphere

i'm using code to embed google maps streetview photo in website. I take the code from the guide:

```
function initialize() {
panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
  document.getElementById('street-view'),
  {
    position: {lat: myLat, lng: myLng},
    pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
    zoom: 1
  });
}
```

In place of myLat and myLng i put latitude and longitude that i take from photo url. Now this work for all type of photo that i found (streetview photo, "see inside" photo) except one "PHOTO SPHERE", i found that there are two type of photo sphere [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIXcq.png)

Now, google recently update google maps and i think that "PHOTO SPHERE" are the new one, and "photo sphere" the oldest, but if i put latitude and longitude of the second, the code works, with the new one it doesn't work, how can i fix?

Example: if i take this url: http://www.google.com/maps/@0.5676777,37.527536,3a,75y,272.82h,93.02t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1st4o4xj2l6HRAma2KT52brg!7i13312!8i6656 with 0.5676777 as myLat and 37.527536 as myLng, the photo is displayed in the website

if i take this: http://www.google.it/maps/@35.91208,14.498901,3a,89.9y,2.16h,87.34t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-bkrM3HFU1vg%2FVhjysw39NSI%2FAAAAAAAAAPk%2F2PLOjiwhbh4!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F-bkrM3HFU1vg%2FVhjysw39NSI%2FAAAAAAAAAPk%2F2PLOjiwhbh4%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i10000!8i5000

35.91208: myLat, 14.498901: myLng

The code not works and no photo is displayed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #street-view {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="street-view"></div>
    <script>
var panorama;
function initialize() {
  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('street-view'),
      {
        position: {lat: 35.91208, lng: 14.498901},
        pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
        zoom: 1
      });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
         src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initialize">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Edited with examples

Comment: That looks like a [custom panorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomPanoramaMethod) (which the documentation says can't be requested by coordinates).

Comment: If it isn't a custom panorama, How can i retrieve the panoid from the url? I can try to embed the photo by panoid in this case..

Comment: I know who have upload this photo, and he uses normal method

Comment: Can he provide the panoid?